# Chrome extensions - loading JavaScript files added by the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

My Chrome extension adds several references to js files (e.g. `<script src="javascript_file_1.js"></script>` ). Using chrome's 'Inspect element' feature I can see that all references are added correctly, however they do not seem to be 'loaded'. Is there any way to 're-execute' the page so these new js files are loaded?

Here is the code I use:

```
var srcArray = ["javascript_file_1.js",
        "javascript_file_2.js",
        "javascript_file_3.js",
        "javascript_file_4.js",
        "javascript_file_5.js",
        "javascript_file_6.js",
        "javascript_file_7.js"];
                
function AddScript(value)
{
    var entry = document.createElement("SCRIPT")
    entry.src = value;
    document.head.appendChild(entry);
    
}
```

They seem to be added after the page got rendered, hence their content was not used while rendering the page.

Comment: What do you mean by loaded?

Comment: They seem to be added after the page got rendered, hence their content was not used on while rendering the page.

Comment: It's not clear from the question... but if you wish to run your JS code in the context of the web page you need to use Content scripts. Something like: chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"}); should work.

Answer (score 0):

Inject your content script with `"run_at" : "document_start"`, scripts injected with this option are injected right after `css injection`, but before DOM is constructed or any other script is run.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

With this option your code is used while rendering the page.